# on mouseover display none previous li

Tags: jquery

i made a function using `mouseover` and it helps me setting the properties of the current `li` element to be displayed none. how can i make it work like that when i put my mouse over a `li` element then it sets the css property of the previous `li` element to `display:none` ?

```
    $('.sub-men-hdr ul li').mouseover(function() {

    $(this).css('display','none');

    });
```

Is there any way we can achieve this by css3 ? cause i tried using

```
.sb-men li:hover:nth-child(-1).mispnhd
{
   display:none;
}
```

but i know it wont accept negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
$('.sub-men-hdr ul li').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).prev().css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: if i want to target a span element in previous li to add class on it would it be like `$(this).prev('.mispnhd').addClass('mispnhd-tail');` ?

Comment: No, `prev()` will point to the previous `li` only not `span` inside that `li`, To find span inside previous li, you can use: `$(this).prev().find('.mispnhd').addClass('mispnhd-tail');`

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
 $('.sub-men-hdr ul li').mouseover(function() {

    $(this).prev().css('display','none');

    });
```